# Python paths/import in standalone programs

Tags: python, import, path

I'm writing a package that is a small application. It is distributed with portable Python, so code has no access to Windows settings.

The program has this structure:

```
mypr
    __init__.py
    gui
        __init.__.py
    prlib
        __init__.py
```

I am trying to do this `from mypr.gui import Gui` in `prlib` but, of course, `mypr` is not defined. I could add it to win path, edit pth file or append `sys.path` with the current directory, but: this will be a portable application and directory will change.

So, how can I be sure that Python will always have `mypr` in the path, both during development and deployment? Without changing *.pth or editing Windows `PATH`. Is there some reasonable hack during runtime to link `mypr`?

Or, is it possible to import a package "relatively"? I tried `from .gui import Gui`, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to be able to access the 'gui' module in the directory above 'prlib' you can achieve that by:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.dirname(__file__), '../'))
```

Then you should be able to import 'gui' via:

```
from gui import Gui
```